# Create user to MySQL with ssh

Tags: mysql, ssh

I'm trying to create an mysql user from ssh with this command :

```
sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@IP "echo "CREATE USER 'NAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MDP'" | mysql"
```

but it's not working

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MDP' at line 1
```

An idea ?

Comment: I'm unsure if this is the only issue but I see unbalanced quotes `"echo "CREATE USER`. You open two `"` but close only one.

Comment: It's a mistake in writing my question, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you seem to be using double-quotes inside a double-quoted string:

```
sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@IP "echo "CREATE USER 'NAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MDP'" | mysql"
                                                                 ^     ^
```

I indicated two points in the above line. The first one opens a double-quoted string. I think you believe the second one will open another double-quoted string, but in fact it *terminates* the first double-quoted string.

Quoting is a tricky thing in shell languages.

I'd suggest this alternative:

```
echo "CREATE USER 'NAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MDP'" | sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@IP "mysql"
```

With this alternative, there are no double-quoted strings inside double-quoted strings.

I am not familiar with `sshpass` so I don't know if it changes this, but in general you can pipe input to `ssh` and have it become the input to the command run remotely (in this case, mysql).

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! unfortunately it does not work.

But I have another error message :

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

And with just ssh :

ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'NAME'@'localhost'

Comment: Remove the `-t` option to your ssh command.

Comment: without -t : ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'NAME'@'localhost'

Comment: There can be several reasons for that error. Either the user already exists, or the user has been created, then deleted. You can try `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` to get a deleted user to be fully dropped. See for more information: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28331

Comment: Hi ! thx to you it's work after try FLUSH PRIVILEGES on target server.

Comment: Makes sense. If you INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE directly on the `mysql.*` privilege tables to make changes, you should execute FLUSH PRIVILEGES. If you use GRANT/REVOKE/CREATE USER/DROP USER, that flush is done for you implicitly.